# If p(x) = $\sum_{k=0}^{10} k^{2} x^{ \underline{k} }$, evaluate $\bigtriangleup ^{6}$ p(x) $| _{x=0}$.

Tags: combinatorics

If p(x) =  $\sum_{k=0}^{10}   k^{2} x^{ \underline{k} }$, evaluate  $\bigtriangleup ^{6}$ p(x) $|  _{x=0}$.

Not sure how to start with this. I know that p(x) =  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}   \bigtriangleup ^{k}$p(0)  $\frac{{x}^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$

If you can help clear this question up, I'd be grateful!

Comment: You should probably say what the underline and the triangle mean, just to be sure.

Comment: My guess is " [coefficient of the] sixth term of the taylor expansion around 0"?

Comment: triangle is the del operator of the calculus of finite differences.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You should know that $\Delta x^{\underline k}=kx^{\underline{k-1}}$ if $k\ge 0$ and that $\Delta 0=0$; if not, you should prove them. In particular this means that $\Delta^6x^{\underline k}=0$ if $k<6$. You also know that $\Delta cf(x)=c\Delta f(x)$ if $c$ is a constant. If you put those pieces together, you should be able to write down $\Delta^6 p(x)$ fairly easily:

- What is $\Delta^6 k^2x^{\underline k}$ when $k<6$?
- What is $\Delta^6 k^2x^{\underline k}$ when $k\ge 6$?

Then substitute $x=0$. Note that substituting $x=0$ wipes out every non-constant term of a polynomial in $x$.